# How to column bind two ffdf

Tags: r, memory-management, bigdata, ff

Suppose two `ffdf` files:

```
library(ff)
ff1 <- as.ffdf(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*10),ncol=10)))
ff2 <- ff1
colnames(ff2) <- 1:10
```

How can I column bind these without loading them into memory? `cbind` doesn't work.

There is the same question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355686/columnbind-ff-data-frames-in-r` but it does not have an MWE and the author abandoned it so I reposted.

Comment: combining without loading into memory...?  What exactly would that look like?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I don't know. I can do a buttload of other things with ff objects without loading the original full data frame into memory, so I thought `cbind` may be possible too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following construct `cbind.ffdf2`, making sure the column names of the two input `ffdf`'s are not duplicate:

```
library(ff)
ff1 <- as.ffdf(data.frame(letA = letters[1:5], numA = 1:5))
ff2 <- as.ffdf(data.frame(letB = letters[6:10], numB = 6:10))

cbind.ffdf2 <- function(d1, d2){
  D1names <- colnames(d1)
  D2names <- colnames(d2)
  mergeCall <- do.call("ffdf", c(physical(d1), physical(d2)))
  colnames(mergeCall) <- c(D1names, D2names)
  mergeCall
}

cbind.ffdf2(ff1, ff2)[,]
```

Result:

```
   letA numA letB numB
1   a    1    f     6
2   b    2    g     7
3   c    3    h     8
4   d    4    i     9
5   e    5    j    10
```

Comment: Elegant solution. If you request this to be incorporated in ffbase, do post a feature request at https://github.com/edwindj/ffbase/issues

Comment: Thanks. Cannot seem to find a 'new feature' category. Enhancement?

Comment: Click 'new issue' and flag it as enhancement

Comment: Raised it. Finding out how to flag it with any label proved beyond my intuition (this or github's UX for noobs is bad), so it stayed un-labeled :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for joining this late.If you want to cbind an arbitrary number of ffdf objects without worrying of duplicate columns. You can try this (building on Audrey's solution).

```
ff1 <- as.ffdf(data.frame(letA = letters[1:5], numA = 1:5))
ff2 <- as.ffdf(data.frame(letA = letters[6:10], numB = 6:10))

cbind.ffdf2 <- function(...){
  argl <- list(...)
  if(length(argl) == 1L){
    return(argl[[1]])
  }else{
    physicalList = NULL
    for(i in 1:length(argl)){
      if(class(argl[[i]]) == "data.frame"){
        physicalList = c(physicalList, physical(as.ffdf(argl[[i]])))
      }else{
        physicalList = c(physicalList, physical(argl[[i]]))
      }

    }
    mergeCall <- do.call("ffdf", physicalList)
    return(mergeCall)
  }

}

cbind.ffdf2(ff1, ff2)
```

It also coarses any data frame object in the list to an ffdf object.