# Data.table setDT functionality in ff/ffbase R packages

Tags: r, data.table, ff, ffbase

Calculate column of conditional means, in `ff/ffbase` packages.
I'm searching for functionality in `ff/ffbase` packages, which allow me for data manipulation similar to carried below with `data.table` package :

```
library(data.table)
irisdf <- as.data.table(iris)
class(irisdf)
#"ffdf"
irisdf[,  NewMean:= mean(Sepal.Length), Species]
```

There is a function for conditional mean in `ffbase`, but, that creates vector of length of number of classes in `irisdf[,5]`:

```
condMean(x = irisdf[,1], index = irisdf[,5], na.rm = FALSE)
```

, and not new vector of length of `nrow(irisdf)`.

As @BondedDust suggested `ave(base)` gives right output :

```
VectorOfMeans <- ave(irisdf[,1], irisdf[,5], FUN=mean)
```

so the final question is, how to add `VectorOfMeans` to `irisdf`, I've tried below code, which works :

```
irisdf=as.ffdf(iris)
VectorOfMeans <- as.ffdf(as.ff(ave(irisdf[,1], irisdf[,5], FUN=mean)))
irisdf <- cbind.ffdf2(df,VectorOfMeans )
```

with [cbind.ffdf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602751/how-to-column-bind-two-ffdf) from *SO* answer, but I suppose, that *SO* question was about something more specific then main, and I suppose there is an easier(faster) way to do that. I would like to be able run `bigglm.ff` on obtained dataset (`irisdf` in example), you should look at my question about merging `VectorOfMeans` and `irisdf` in this context (as there are issues with physical/virtual modes of storage which I don't understand in details).

Comment: I do not think that the machine and data constraints are clear. And there are assignment methods that accept an "i"-argument See ?'[<-.ff'` and `?'[<-.ffdf'` for the help page for the assignment functions for such objects.

Comment: @BondedDust yes there is even `condMean`, for conditional mean, but length of output is number of classes, not the number of rows in dataset and classes labels aren't treated as variable.

Comment: In base R this would a problem for the `ave` function. You posted no minimal test case for even the simplest of tests.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me ... not being an ff user .... whether one could or couldn't use ordinary functions with ff-vectors. Hence my suggestion that you post a reproducible example. You posted a data.table example, ... now post an ff example. Your irisdf is NOT an ffdf object when that code runs on my machine.

Comment: @BondedDust you are right about `ave`

Comment: @Qbik May be you could check `ffdfdply` from `library(ffbase)`

Comment: @akrun could you provide answer with `ffdfdply` ? `ave` seems to break on large datasets (>40m obs), I've just tested it

Comment: @Qbik I posted a solution.  Please check if that works

Comment: @BondedDust is there with identical output as `ave` but accepting `factor` as grouping variable ?

Comment: `ave` should accept a factor index/grouping vector.

Comment: @BondedDust it seems that I have too large number of levels in factor, (without error message) or mayby there is problem, when working with large `ffdf` objects and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(data.table)
library(ffbase)
x1 <- as.ffdf(iris)
fd1 <- ffdfdply(x1, split=as.character(x1$Species), FUN=function(x) {
 x2 <- as.data.table(x)
 res <- x2[, NewMean:= mean(Sepal.Length), Species]
 as.data.frame(res)
}, trace=T)
```