# Binding several large matrices by column

Tags: sql, r, memory-management, matrix, bigdata

I truly know that 'large matrix issue' is a recurrent topic here, but I would like to explain minutely my specific problem regarding large matrices.

Strictly speaking, I want to `cbind` several large matrices with a specific name pattern in R. The below code shows my best try until this point.

First lets produce files to mimetize my real matrices:

```
# The df1
df1 <- '######## infx infx infx
######## infx infx infx
probeset_id sample1 sample2 sample3
PR01           1       2       0
PR02           -1      2       0
PR03            2      1       1
PR04           1       2       1
PR05           2       0       1'
df1 <- read.table(text=df1, header=T, skip=2)
write.table(df1, "df1.txt", col.names=T, row.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")

# The df2 
df2 <- '######## infx infx infx
######## infx infx infx
probeset_id sample4 sample5 sample6
PR01           2       2       1
PR02           2      -1       0
PR03            2      1       1
PR04           1       2       1
PR05           0       0       1'
df2 <- read.table(text=df2, header=T, skip=2)
write.table(df2, "df2.txt", col.names=T, row.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")

# The dfn 
dfn <- '######## infx infx infx
######## infx infx infx
probeset_id samplen1 samplen2 samplen3
PR01           2       -1       1
PR02           1      -1       0
PR03            2      1       1
PR04           1       2       -1
PR05           0       2       1'
dfn <- read.table(text=dfn, header=T, skip=2)
write.table(dfn, "dfn.txt", col.names=T, row.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")
```

Then import it to R and write as my expected `output` file:

```
### Importing and excluding duplicated 'probeset_id' column
calls = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
library(data.table)
calls = lapply(calls, fread, header=T)
mycalls <- as.data.frame(calls)
probenc <- as.data.frame(mycalls[,1])
mycalls <- mycalls[, -grep("probe", colnames(mycalls))]
output <- cbind(probenc, mycalls)
names(output)[1] <- "probeset_id"
write.table(output, "output.txt", col.names=T, row.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")
```

How the output looks like:

```
> head(output)
  probeset_id sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6 samplen1 samplen2 samplen3
1        PR01       1       2       0       2       2       1        2       -1        1
2        PR02      -1       2       0       2      -1       0        1       -1        0
3        PR03       2       1       1       2       1       1        2        1        1
4        PR04       1       2       1       1       2       1        1        2       -1
5        PR05       2       0       1       0       0       1        0        2        1
```

This code works perfectly for what I want to do, however, I face the known R memory limitation using my real data (more than 30 "`df`" objects with ~1.3GB or/and 600k rows by 100 columns each).

I read about a very interesting SQL approach ([R: how to rbind two huge data-frames without running out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761073/r-how-to-rbind-two-huge-data-frames-without-running-out-of-memory)) but I am inexperienced in SQL and did not found a way to adaptate it to my case.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had misunderstood the question previously; now the comment made it clear. What you need then is to work with a package like `ff`. This lets you work with files from your hard disk as opposed to loading them in RAM. This looks like a solution to your problem as you mention that RAM is not enough to load all the files in your system.

First of all load the files with `read.table.ffdf` and then use the following to cbind them together:

```
#load files in R
library(ff)

df1 <- read.table.ffdf('df1.txt', header=T, skip=2)
df2 <- read.table.ffdf('df2.txt', header=T, skip=2)
dfn <- read.table.ffdf('dfn.txt', header=T, skip=2)
```

And then merge like this:

```
mergedf <- do.call('ffdf', c(physical(df1), physical(df2), physical(dfn)))
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use your example as `read.table.ffdf` does not support the text argument, but the above should work. The `ff` package has its own (not very complex) syntax that you might need to familiarize yourself with as it works with files off of your hard disk. For example `apply` functions are done using the `ffapply` function in pretty much the same way as `apply`.

Have a look [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ff/docs/read.table.ffdf), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602751/how-to-column-bind-two-ffdf) and [here](http://ff.r-forge.r-project.org/bit&ff2.1-2_WU_Vienna2010.pdf) for some basic tutorials on package `ff`.

You can also see the functions inside the package and use the in-built help to help yourself with `ls(package:ff)`.

Comment: The main problem is that my memory crashs before reading all my big matrices into R environment. That´s why I did the code to produce those 3 "df" text files. My real question is how to create a concetenated file (as my output.txt) without running out memory.

Comment: I have updated answer with a recommended solution now that I have understood the problem.